# Compiling C program with assembly function and vice versa

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86

I've got a problem with my program. When I'm trying to compile my C program with assembly function using this line:

```
gcc -o program factarial.c
```

I get this and I don't know why:

```
/tmp/ccFKqbDP.o: In function `main':
factarial.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `factarial_asm'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void factarial_asm();

int main ()
{
 factarial_asm (5);
 return 0;
}
```

And this is assembly code:

```
.data
.text
.global _main
.type factarial_asm, @function

factarial_asm:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl $1, %eax
je koniec
    decl %eax
    pushl %eax
call factarial_asm
    movl 8(%ebp), %ebx
    mull %ebx
koniec:
leave
ret
```

Also, when I'm trying to compile asm code with C function using this line:

```
gcc -o program factarial.s
```

I get this problem:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccWCmTBe.o: In function `main':
(.text+0x3): undefined reference to `factarial'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my asm code:

```
SYSEXIT = 1
EXIT_SUCC = 0
SYSWRITE = 4
SYSCALL = 0x80
SYSREAD = 3

.align 32
.text
.global _main
main:

pushl $5
call factarial

movl $SYSEXIT, %eax
movl $EXIT_SUCC, %ebx
int $SYSCALL
```

And my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factarial(int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    else       return n * factarial(n - 1);
}
```

I know that it's so much questions, but so far I was preparing as compiler and ld linker so I don't exactly know how to use gcc.
Also, could anyone help me with preparing makefile file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is each of your compilation lines are trying to create your executable without the full program. You somewhat complicate things if your source files are the same name with a different extension.

One simple option is instead, this command: `gcc -o program factarial.c factarial.s`.

Alternatively you might consider compiling but not linking your individual source files, and then linking their objects together to build your executable. Assuming your source files were named `a.c` and `b.s`, you would:

```
gcc -c a.c
gcc -c b.s
gcc -o program a.o b.o
```

Finally (and not related to your problem, of course), I believe the word you are looking for is `factorial` :)

---

There still exists a problem in your assembly. First, I've recreated your results, as seen here:

```
$ gcc -c factarial.c
$ gcc -c factarial_asm.s
$ gcc -o program factarial.o factarial_asm.o
factarial.o: In function `main':
factarial.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `factarial_asm'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Next, I used the `nm` command to inspect the object files:

```
$ nm factarial.o
                 U factarial_asm
0000000000000000 T main
$ nm factarial_asm.o
                 U _main
0000000000000000 t factarial_asm
000000000000001a t koniec
```

There are some interesting things in the `nm` output for the assembly object. First, `U _main` tells us that `main()` is undefined in that object, meaning it's expected to be found when we link the program. This file doesn't call `main()` so we really shouldn't even care about that. This is caused by `.global _main`, which can safely be removed.

Next, the symbol for `factarial_asm` is a lower case `t`, not the `T` found in `main()` from the primary C source... being shown as `t` means the symbol is local to that source file only, it's not exported to others. (In C, this is the difference between `void function() {}` and `static void function() {}`). We need to fix that, by adding the proper `.global` directive.

**Summarized:** in your assembly, change `.global _main` to `.global factarial_asm`.

Comment: Unfortunately, problem stay the same:
[Sorry, for external link, but I wanted it to be more clear.](http://pastebin.com/ddgrvw2V)

Comment: I just noticed your main() is an assembly function. Try renaming it from `main:` to `_main:`. You may also need to change `call factarial` to `call _factarial`.

Comment: It's still doesn't work. I think it could be problem with order of compiling programs, because it doesn't see the main, but I don't get how to repair it.

Comment: I was able to get it to compile with a few changes. First, the _ is not necessary for me (it could be for you, it depends on the compiler). Second, you must add `.global factarial_asm` in the top of your assembly file! Third (for me, you probably don't need this) I had to change the pushl instructions to be 64 bit instructions. That got me to build, but it crashed when running; you'll need to figure out the crash if you hit it also (or post a new question for it, but if you're on a 32 bit system maybe it'll work for you). I'll edit my answer shortly to give additional help.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! Now, everything works fine! Thank you!! :)